# How can I gather all the tags for a Feature file?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to leverage the tag names that are associated with a feature file in my cucumber ruby Framework. Below is what I am currently doing to gather the tag names using a Before hook, but unfortunately more code other than just the tags are being collected.

```
Before do |scenario|
  @feature_tags = scenario.feature.tags
end
```

Take for example this sample feature file snippet:

```
@regression @etc
Feature: File description for something

Background:
* etc etc etc

Scenario: Description for something
* etc etc etc
```

What is currently being captured with the above hook is:

```
[#<Cucumber::Core::Ast::Tag "@regression" (features/long/file/path.feature:1)>, 
#<Cucumber::Core::Ast::Tag "@etc" (features/long/file/path.feature:1)>]
```

Is there any way that I can isolate simply the tag names ie: "@regression" ?

Comment: Hey Welcome to SO. Do you want to exclude the Background tag from the scenario tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
scenario.source_tag_names
```

Comment: That solution only works for the tag names of scenarios, not the overall Feature tags.